# Crazydomain setting for parseapp.com

Tags: parse-platform, web-hosting

I am desperately trying to connect my domain to something.parseapp.com. I have tried a few settings but none of them works. My settings are in the following picture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The image is so small that I can not read. Can you re-upload it with higher resolution? Btw, are you going to use `yourdomain.com` or `www.yourdomain.com` to direct to `yourparse.parseapp.com`???

Comment: sorry mate, I am going to use my domain www.jorc.com.au to be hosted by parse.com app ie golfer.parseapp.com.    crazydomains.com.au is only the domain provide and I have to do settings there.

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot of when you enter the information? I  am no longer using Crazy Domains so I forgot how it looks like. I checked your configuration and seeing that you are pointing to `golfer.parseapp.com.jorc.com.au` but  not `golfer.parseapp.com`

Comment: I have added a second screenshot, fyi it doesnt allow me to leave any of the fields empyt.

Comment: Can you change the NS for your domain? If it's possible, I suggest you to use Cloudflare to mange. It's easier.

Comment: how u doing with this? I got the same issues mate

Comment: See below for solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I search around and find a solution for you here: http://blog.kchandrahasa.com/blog/2013/07/09/crazydomains-crazy-issues/

Below is a summary with my own experience, just in case the link is dead in future.

---

In order to change CNAME records in Crazy Domains, you have to pay for it. For a cheaper solution, you can change the nameservers of your domain to other free DNS management services like:

- [cloudns.net](http://cloudns.net)
- [freedns.afraid.org](http://freedns.afraid.org/)
- [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)

I suggest you to use CloudFlare since it's more powerful and support many features. Proceed as below:

1. Create an account in Cloudflare
2. Once you login, you will have to add your domain name.
3. It will scan your DNS settings.
4. After it finishes scanning, proceed with "I'm done entering my DNS records".
5. Take note of the 2 nameservers Cloudflare provides you at this step.

Now come back to Crazy Domains, login to your account.

1. Click on Domains and click Update Name Servers under DNS settings.
2. Delete the existing crazy domains name servers and enter the two nameservers given by Cloudflare. It will take up to 24 hours, but in my experience it will be just some hours.
   [image]

Now come back at CloudFlare and enter your CNAME as instructed by Parse.

Comment: Thanks Kodi, I have issue with changing the name server as I lose my email hosting connection. My email hosting is with crazy domains and they want me to leave the name servers as it is. I can change A record and CNAME.

Comment: You mean you can change the CNAME to Parse already and you have resolved your issue?

Comment: No it is not. I can change the CNAME but parse cant resolve it so there is no website.

Comment: One issue though I have now. I get a blue screen when typing www.jorc.com.au saying Parse App not found
We don't seem to have an app at this host name.
It might not be configured correctly, or may have moved.

Comment: Regarding the comment above my setting the box asking for host name in parse.com is left empty. Otherwise I don't even the error above.

Comment: What is your current setting in CloudFlare? Please share the screenshot here.

Comment: Are you still using NS from crazydomains? I can see it here: http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3awww.jorc.com.au&run=toolpage#

Comment: I'll send it tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Kodi, I added parse setting, if I add anything in the bottom box, it doesnt show anything. But if I leave empty it goes to a page with a blue box saying parse app is not configured properly.

Comment: Please post your screenshot in the comment here

Comment: I am using name severs only from Cloudflare.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your Cloudflare DNS setting?

Comment: Kodi, actually it is going well now, it seems my website is up and running. I have to thank you a lot. The last thing I needed to do is to type www.jorc.com.au in my parse app setting.